# How to truncate a floating point number to two decimal points in postgres procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to truncate a floating point number to two decimal points. for eg:- the number 14.141244804178488 should become 14.14. Till now i have tried like this

```
var_A float;
var_A := 14.141244804178488;
select  trunc(var_A ,2) into  var_A; 
raise notice '%', var_A;
```

when i am trying to execute this query, i am getting an exception in the above query. I also tried to solve using the below query;

```
/*var_A float;
var_A := 14.141244804178488;*/
select  trunc(141244804178488 ,2) into  var_A; 
raise notice '%', var_A;
```

For the above query i am getting the output 14.1400000000000006. Can  anyone help me in this.

Comment: Don't use `select` for simple variable assignment. `var_a := trunc(var_A ,2);` would be a lot better (and faster)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `trunc()` function *with second parameter* for `float` data type.

So, change `var_A float` to `var_A numeric` and try:

( As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed, better is to assign variable using `:=` operator, instead of `select..into`

```
do $$
declare
    var_A numeric;
begin
    var_A := 14.141244804178488; 
    var_A := trunc(var_A ,2); 
    raise notice '%', var_A;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Don't use `select` for simple variable assignment. `var_a := trunc(var_A ,2);` would be a lot better (and faster)